# A Rough Estimation for the number of square free integers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Show by a sieve argument that the number of square free integers not exceeding $x$ is less than $$x\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)+o(x),$$where the product extends over all primes.

I happened to see this exercise this morning, and still fail to prove it. Could you give me a proof?

Answer (score 5):

Rough sketch:  Have you seen the [Wikipedia section on the distribution of squarefree integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution)?  It essentially gives your solution.  All you need to notice is that for large $n$, the "probability" that an integer has $p^2$ as a factor is $\frac{p^2-1}{p^2} = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)$.  Since the probability that $n$ has $p^2$ as a factor is roughly independent of the fact it has $q^2$  where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, this implies that

$$
\frac{Q(x)}{x} \approx  \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^2} \right).
$$

I will leave it to you to make this precise.